# Input not being submitted from a Web2Py / Python form

Tags: python, forms, input, web2py

I am trying to create a comments section using Web2Py/Python, I have created the form with no errors, but when the form submits the comments are not completely added. Can anyone spot something I am missing?

db1.py modal:

```
db.define_table('products',
            Field('Product_Name',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('Product_Description',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('Product_Review',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            auth.signature)

db.define_table('product_comments',
            Field('products', 'reference products'),
            Field('body', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            auth.signature)
```

default.py controller:

```
def show():
post = db.products(request.args(0, cast=int))
productDescription = T("Product Description")
productReview = T("Product Review")
back = T("Back")
#commentHeading = T("Comments")
db.product_comments.products.default = post.id
db.product_comments.products.readable = False
db.product_comments.products.writable = False
comments = db(db.product_comments.products==post.id).select()
form = SQLFORM(db.product_comments).process()
return locals()
```

default/show.html view:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h1>{{=XML(post.Product_Name, sanitize=True)}}</h1>

<h2>{{=XML(productDescription, sanitize=True)}}</h2>
{{=XML(post.Product_Description, sanitize=True)}}


<h2>{{=XML(productReview, sanitize=True)}}</h2>
{{=XML(post.Product_Review, sanitize=True)}}

<h2>Comments</h2>

{{for comment in comments:}}
<div class="well">
    {{=comment.created_by.first_name}} {{=comment.created_by.last_name}}
    on {{=comment.created_on}} says
    {{comment.body}}
</div>
{{pass}}

{{=XML(form, sanitize=True)}}

<a href="/ReviewMyProduct/default/index">{{=XML(back, sanitize=True)}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed an `=` inside `{{comment.body}}` to make it look like `{{=comment.body}}`. However Anthony's answer is customary if you want the comments section to show the body based on index.

Without it, submitting a comment would post the previous submitted comment (always one behind).

Comment: Be that as is may, I am still receiving an error when posting comments because now my first_name is not matching an attribute, even though I have assigned an auth.signature on the both databases.

Error:
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>('NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name')

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, you are selecting the existing comments *before* processing the form (which inserts the new comment), so the newly submitted comment will not be included in the comments shown on the page. Just reverse the order of the last two lines:

```
    form = SQLFORM(db.product_comments).process()
    comments = db(db.product_comments.products==post.id).select()
```

Also, you should get rid of all of the `XML(..., sanitize=True)` calls, as they are completely unnecessary. That is for when you need to bypass the default escaping in the template but need to sanitize because the content is untrusted. In this case, you do not need to bypass the escaping of any of the content.

Comment: I did this but now I have an <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>('NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name') error even though I have the auth.signature attribute in both tables. Thank you for the reply and sorry for my slow reply Anthony.

Comment: Is it possible for comments to be added without being logged in? If so, such comments would not have a value in the `created_by` field.